# Missing include "bits/c++config.h" when cross compiling 64 bit program on 32 bit in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, g++, 32bit-64bit, cross-compiling, ubuntu-10.10

I am running the 32bit version of Ubuntu 10.10 and trying to cross compile to a 64 bit target. Based on my research, I have installed the g++-multilib package.

The program is a very simple hello world:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -m64 main.cpp
```

Error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:39: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I have found a `c++config.h` file but they reside under the `i486-linux-gnu` and `i686-linux-gnu` directories in `/usr/include/c++/4.4/` There is not `c++config.h` in `/usr/include/c++/bits`.

Any ideas on what I am missing? Compiling without the `-m64` flag works fine (a.out is created and runs correctly).

**Edit** Thanks to the hint from @nightcracker, I did a little more investigation into the include structure on the 32 and 64 bit systems. I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/missing-include-bits-cconfig-h-when-cross-compiling-64-bit-program-on-32-bit/4643464#4643464) below that "fixes" the problem temporarily but I think it will break on the next update. Basically, I am missing a directory called `/usr/include/c++/4.4/i686-linux-gnu/64` that should contain a subdirectory called `bits` that has the missing include file. Any idea what package should be taking care of this?

Comment: Wow... I had this problem too. GCC 4.8 on a ARMv7-a CubieTruck (Cortex-A7) running Ubuntu. The bizarre thing (to me) is, Anthony's answer fixed it. Whatever...

Answer (score 384, accepted):

Adding this answer partially because it fixed my problem of the same issue and so I can bookmark this question myself.

I was able to fix it by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

If you've installed a version of `gcc` / `g++` that doesn't ship by default (such as `g++-4.8` on lucid) you'll want to match the version as well:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-multilib g++-4.8-multilib
```

Comment: Make sure to match the versions of `gcc and g++` installed on your system. On Ubuntu 14.04 I had `gcc-4.8` and `g++-4.8` installed, so I installed `gcc-4.8-multilib ` and `g++-4.8-multilib` instead.

Comment: This solved my problem when compiling with -m32 on a 64-bit machine. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib` seems better (it resolves to your gcc version automatically).

Comment: ^maybe not! @Zoltan's suggestion worked for me though. Anthony Sottile, maybe you should incorporate Zoltan's comment in your answer?

Comment: @Man feel free to suggest an edit, when I initially posted it I matched the version asked in the question, it has since changed from other's edits

Comment: This also happens on windows which do not happen to have apt-get.

Comment: @TomášZato the question says "Ubuntu" -- perhaps ask a new one for windows?

Comment: Works for me on Utuntu 16.04 x64 version, when try to compile with -m32 flag. Before bits/c++config.h  not found,  sys/cdefs.h also not found, which is resolved by install  libc6-dev-i386 package.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 17.14. Thank you!

Comment: It is disappointing that the 32 bit gcc/g++ compiler is not included complete.  You get smaller, faster programs for your 4 bit system with 32 bit compile when you have no data structures or stack growth > 4GB.

Answer (score 14):

Did you try adding `-I/usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu` or `-I/usr/include/c++/4.4/i686-linux-gnu`?

Comment: That does indeed work. Any idea on why I would need to do this for only 64 bit? I am trying to set this machine up to help with distributed 64 bit builds and want to avoid too much customization.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea, I just posed a quick hacky working solution :)

Comment: simply because "bits/c++config.h" resides there :)

Answer (score 11):

While compiling in RHEL 6.2 (x86_64), I installed both 32bit and 64bit libstdc++-dev packages, but I had the *"c++config.h no such file or directory*" problem.

Resolution:

The directory `/usr/include/c++/4.4.6/x86_64-redhat-linux` was missing.

I did the following:

```
cd /usr/include/c++/4.4.6/
mkdir x86_64-redhat-linux
cd x86_64-redhat-linux
ln -s ../i686-redhat-linux 32
```

I'm now able to compile 32bit binaries on a 64bit OS.

Comment: On OpenSUSE I did `cd /usr/include/c++/4.6;ln -s x86_64-suse-linux i586-suse-linux`

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be a typo error in that package of gcc. The solution:

```
mv /usr/include/c++/4.x/i486-linux-gnu /usr/include/c++/4.x/i686-linux-gnu/64
```

Answer (score 3):

On my 64 bit system I noticed that the following directory existed:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/32/bits
```

It would then make sense that on my 32 bit system that had been setup for 64bit cross compiling there should be a corresponding directory like:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits
```

I double checked and this directory did not exist. Running `g++` with the verbose parameter showed that the compiler was actually looking for something in this location:

```
jesse@shalored:~/projects/test$ g++ -v -m64 main.cpp 
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-m64' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib 64 -D_GNU_SOURCE main.cpp -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -m64 -mtune=generic -auxbase main -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccMvIfFH.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/4.4/i686-linux-gnu/64"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../i686-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.4
 /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) version 4.4.5 (i686-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.4.5, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.0-p3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=98 --param ggc-min-heapsize=128197
Compiler executable checksum: 1fe36891f4a5f71e4a498e712867261c
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:39: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The error regarding the `ignoring nonexistent directory` was the clue. Unfortunately, I still don't know what package I need to install to have this directory show up so I just copied the `/usr/include/c++/4.4/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits` directory from my 64 bit machine to `/usr/include/c++/4.4/i686-linux-gnu/64/bits` on my 32 machine.

Now compiling with just the `-m64` works correctly. The major drawback is that this is still not the correct way to do things and I am guessing the next time Update Manager installs and update to g++ things may break.

Comment: Nice debugging technique!

Answer (score 3):

Basically It is used in HeapOverflows or other reversing type Problems i.e. If you want to change a 64 bit ELF to 32 bit ELF and it is showing error while converting.

You can simply run the commands

```
apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

which will update your libraries
Packages upgraded:

> The following additional packages will be installed:
>     g++-8-multilib gcc-8-multilib lib32asan5 lib32atomic1 lib32gcc-8-dev
>     lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32mpx2 lib32quadmath0 lib32stdc++-8-dev
>     lib32ubsan1 libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386
>     libc6-dev-x32 libc6-i386 libc6-x32 libx32asan5 libx32atomic1
>     libx32gcc-8-dev libx32gcc1 libx32gomp1 libx32itm1 libx32quadmath0
>     libx32stdc++-8-dev libx32stdc++6 libx32ubsan1
>   Suggested packages:
>     lib32stdc++6-8-dbg libx32stdc++6-8-dbg glibc-doc
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:
>     g++-8-multilib g++-multilib gcc-8-multilib gcc-multilib lib32asan5
>     lib32atomic1 lib32gcc-8-dev lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32mpx2
>     lib32quadmath0 lib32stdc++-8-dev lib32ubsan1 libc6-dev-i386
>     libc6-dev-x32 libc6-x32 libx32asan5 libx32atomic1 libx32gcc-8-dev
>     libx32gcc1 libx32gomp1 libx32itm1 libx32quadmath0 libx32stdc++-8-dev
>     libx32stdc++6 libx32ubsan1

similar to this will be shown to your terminal

Comment: On Debian 10 a number of packages that I want to keep would have been removed. The following packages will be REMOVED:
  g++-8-arm-linux-gnueabi g++-8-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-arm-linux-gnueabi
  g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-8-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-8-arm-linux-gnueabi
  gcc-8-arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
  gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

Answer (score 2):

This bug is fixed in "gcc-4.6".

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.5/+bug/793411

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem while cross-compiling on x86 machine for arm32, if you are cross-compiling then for arm then make sure you have installed the latest libstdc++ pkg.

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-10-dev-armhf-cross
```

Then you may run into another header error which is 'asm/errno.h' file not found. Just install gcc-multilib for this.

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib
```

Comment: Thank you. Same use case for me too. I also had to do a `sudo apt install g++-multilib libstdc++-9-dev-armhf-cross`

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib` helps. But my another issue is that I FORGET to clean the directory so I still get the same error. It is the first time to use clang or cmake. So I just delete my original directory and re-compile and it works. Hope it helps someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it only has been a path issue. I reduced the path length of my source files and it worked...

Comment: ??? Please share an example. "path length of .. source files" really shouldn't ever be a problem. How is it that you had a src file path that was too long?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to recreate the problem right now. It happened on a Windows system which may have (note: does not apply in all cases) a path limitation of 260 chars.