# Cannot open source file "bits/c++config.h" error with icpc

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, icc, ubuntu-13.10

I am trying to compile a program on a 64-bit machine with icpc. Unfortunately, I get an error message of `catastrophic error: cannot open source file "bits/c++config.h"`. I have adopded some advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/missing-include-bits-cconfig-h-when-cross-compiling-64-bit-program-on-32-bit/4643217#4643217) but with no success. Also, I do not forget to run `source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64` before hand and I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 in case this is important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, find the missing file:

```
find /usr -name c++config.h
```

(Headers are in **/usr**, most of the time.) Then, add its top dir to the include path of your compilation command, so the compiler will find "bits/c++config.h", using the **-I** option. A similar question was already asked on SO, BTW: [Missing include "bits/c++config.h" when cross compiling 64 bit program on 32 bit in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have seen the topic you suggest, though haven't found solution there. Anyway, your solution worked for me!

Answer (score 10):

For some reason the icpc compiler doesn't parse the following directory. You can set the following variable; replace 4.8 by your g++ version

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8
```