# how to compile g++ app and run anywhere?

Tags: linux, g++

my program compiled and worked fine with:

```
g++ main.cpp exm1.cpp exm2.cpp -o main.o
```

i want to compile this app and run anywhere
how can i?
i try this code

```
g++ -g -Wall -I/MyApp/lib -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static main.cpp exm1.cpp exm2.cpp -o main.o
```

but not work
in lib folder has 2 files:

- exm1.h
- exm2.h

  main.cpp included:

> ```
> #include <fstream>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <string>
> #include <streambuf>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include "lib/exm1.h"
> #include "lib/exm2.h"
> ```

my linux is kali, and i want run this app on CentOS 6
please help me,thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "run anywhere"? What do you mean by "but not work"?

Comment: Oh, and have you tried to just use `-static` to link *all* libraries statically?

Comment: i compiled in kali and run main.o , and work fine, but main.o not work on centos

Comment: i want to compile this app on kali, and run in centos without compile

Comment: Please be more specific. When you say that running the progran doesn't work, *how* doesn't it work? What happens when you run it? Do you get any messages? You might want to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: when i run main.o in centos, not work, `-bash: ./main.o: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: if you type `file main.o` what you see? I expect your executable uses shared libs.

Comment: `main.o: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, from '8@%rdi 8@%rsi', not stripped`

Comment: is your centOS 64 bit?

Comment: i think is 32bit, `Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Sun May 6 05:24:22 EDT 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Comment: On an unrelated note, the filename suffix `.o` is usually use for *object* files. Executable files usually don't have a suffix (also known as an extension) at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from comments one reason could be you executable is 64-bit and centOS a 32-bit sytem. Try compilation with `-m32` flag.

Comment: `/usr/include/c++/4.9/iosfwd:38:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/c++config.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/missing-include-bits-cconfig-h-when-cross-compiling-64-bit-program-on-32-bit seems a frequent issue

Answer (score 1):

As C. bear said, use the `-m32` flag so the program is able to run on 64- and 32- bit systems. In doing this, You'll also have to install the 32bit stdlibs. I'm not sure how to do this on kali, give it a google. Another thing you can do to avoid having users install external libraries (if you use them at any point) is to statically link you executable. Use the `-static` flag to do this. However, because all your app's dependencies (including the stdlibs) will be in a single file, it will get pretty big. On the other hand, loading times will be better, because your app doesn't have to run the dynamic linker and wait for it to link your external libraries as you call them.

Answer (score 0):

> how to compile g++ app and run anywhere?

It is not easily possible. For example, an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable produced by [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) on a recent [Debian](https://debian.org/)/x86-64 computer won't run on a [RaspberryPi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) (with a linux for ARM 32 bits, e.g. some Raspbian)

Read more about [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and about [fat binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary)

Be aware that the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler suite can be built (from its source code) as a cross-compiler (but you'll need to rebuild GCC for every different target system).

I recommend to invoke GCC as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` during the debugging phase (and use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Once your software is debugged, compile it with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O2` to get an optimized binary (or even compile and link it with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -flto`)