# bits/c++config.h no such file or directory

Tags: c, qt, include, iostream, bit

I'm trying to compile my code including iostream lib on ubuntu 14.04, using qt creator, but when I execute it I got this error message:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:38: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory #include <bits/c++config.h>
```

Even if I try to compile it by terminal, I have the same trouble.
This is a c code that i got from my friend, not c++, but I still need to include this iostream. I made a huge research and can't find anything useful on internet, just posts talking about 64 or 32 bits OS. I'm new on programming scene, I'm glad for your patience, thanks.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/missing-include-bits-cconfig-h-when-cross-compiling-64-bit-program-on-32-bit) help?

Answer (score 10):

It does look like a cross-platform compilation issue. Did you install the multilib packages:

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

If you've installed a version of `gcc` / `g++` that doesn't ship by default you'll want to match the version as well:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-multilib g++-4.8-multilib
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14391677/1349673).

Comment: Or just 'sudo apt-get install g++-multilib'

Comment: @MikeW or just "apt" instead of "apt-get"

Comment: 'sudo apt install {gcc,g++}-multilib`