# How to change the entry point of a g++ generated Linux shared library compiled from multiple source files?

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-14.04

Today, I read the [web blog article](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/executable_lib.html), How to make executable shared libraries . In this article it states that if one types at a Linux command prompt:

```
gcc -shared service.c -o libservice.so -Wl,-soname,libservice.so -W1,-e lib_entry
```

followed by

```
./libservice.so, then we can directly executer the lib_entry function.
```

However, when I run a similar g++ command:

```
g++ -shared one.cpp two.cpp three.cpp -o libservice.so -Wl,-soname,libservice.so -W1,-e lib_entry
```

where `lib_entry` is a `C` function defined in `two.cpp` I get the warning message:

> No entry point lib_entry point found.

How do I fix this warning message so I can directly run the entry point, `lib_entry`? Should I enclose the implementation of the `C` function `foo` with `extern "C"` linkage to resolve this problem?

Comment: "Should I enclose the implemenation of the C function foo with extern "C" linkage to resolve this problem?" - have you tried it? did it resolve the problem?

Comment: Maybe something to do with `C++` name mangling? Did you make the entry function `C` linkage?

Comment: @immibis, I will try your suggestion in 5 minutes. Thank you and Happy New Year.

Comment: @Galik, I will try to make the entry function C linkage shortly. Happ New Year.

Comment: Can't you format the post clearly please?

Comment: I wrapped the entry point lib_entry in exten "C" linkage and compiled with 
  Accessing a corrupted shared library

Comment: @immibis,@Galik I tried extern "C" linkage and compiled with  g++   -shared -fPIC -DLINUX -I /home/venkat/Downloads/waitForMultipleObjects -I /home/venkat/developmentMono/SmartCamXi_Hybrid/Include  -efunc DataServer.cpp DataServerLib.cpp DataTransferClient.cpp CWinEventHandle.cpp WinEvent.cpp -lpthread -lrt -o myprogBC.so
Then I ran this ; $ ./myprogBC.so. Then I got the error message: 
  Accessing a corrupted shared library which means that I am on a 64 bit system trying to make a 32 bit library. When I try: g++ -m32, I get : bits/c++config.h: No such file/directory : How do I fix this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Could you please try to solve this problem? Even when I use g++ -m64 , I get the error message: Accessing a corrupted shared library. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer: 
[Missing include "bits/c++config.h" when cross compiling 64 bit program on 32 bit in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/missing-include-bits-cconfig-h-when-cross-compiling-64-bit-program-on-32-bit)

sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-multilib g++-4.9-multilib

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, Could you please try to solve this problem? Even when I use g++ -m64 , I get the error message: Accessing a corrupted shared library. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Please disregard the previous answer. The answer below was tested successfully. Thank you for your patience.
Step 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef __LP64__
const char service_interp[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";
#else
const char service_interp[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib/ld-linux.so.2";
#endif


void lib_service(void)
{

  printf("This is a service of the shared library\n");

} // lib_service
void lib_entry(void)
{
  printf("Entry point of the service library\n");
 _exit(0);
}
```

Step 2.

```
vendor@clickit:~/Downloads/DataServerLib$ g++   -shared -fPIC -DLINUX -Wl,-soname,libdataserver.so -efunc  -I /home/vendor/Downloads/waitForMultipleObjects -I /home/vendor/development/Test/Include  DataServer.cpp DataServerLib.cpp DataTransferClient.cpp CWinEventHandle.cpp WinEvent.cpp -o libDataServer.so -lpthread -lrt
maryych@uwash.edu:~/Downloads/DataServerLib$ chmod 777 libDataServer.so
maryych@uwash.edu:~/Downloads/DataServerLib$ ./libDataServer.so
```

Inside entry point tester 1
AddUser

Comment: @Olaf, Please checkout this answer and delete the previous answer when you have time.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit  I just formatted  answer #2. Thank you.