# using g++ with -m32 on travis results in an error

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, travis-ci

I am installing these packages: `g++-4.7` `gcc-4.7-multilib` and I set `CXX` to `g++-4.7`

I validate that the compiler is indeed 4.7 by issuing `${CXX} --version`

after that I call cmake like this:

`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-m32" .`

My project has only c++ source files so no need for C flags. The errors I get on travis are:

`/usr/include/c++/4.7/cstdio:43:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory`

any ideas? I have no problems using `-m64`

**EDIT**:

just tried also with `g++-4.7-multilib` (g++ instead of gcc) but still no luck - same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the log and saw this...

```
Installing APT Packages (BETA)
Disallowing packages: g\+\+-4.7-multilib
If you require these packages, please review the package approval process at:
https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist#package-approval-process
```

turns out taht only for gcc 4.6 and 4.7 the package is not in the whitelist - other gcc versions have it... will request it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you ran into this: [Missing include "bits/c++config.h" when cross compiling 64 bit program on 32 bit in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/missing-include-bits-cconfig-h-when-cross-compiling-64-bit-program-on-32-bit)

Make sure that you have the same versions of gcc, g++, gcc-multilib and g++-multilib installed and if that doesn't help, try adding `-I/usr/include/c++/4.7/i686-linux-gnu` to CXXFLAGS