# c++config.h in Fedora 29

Tags: gcc, g++, fedora

I'm trying to compile simple c++ file and keep getting this problem

> /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:38:10: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory

I also found `c++config.h` file here: `/usr/include/c++/8/i686-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h`

I've found a solution for Ubuntu with installing `gcc-multilib` but this does not work for fedora (Error: Unable to find a match). I probably have  *g++* installed with *gcc-c++.*

Answer (score 3):

> /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:38:10: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
>
> I also found c++config.h file here: /usr/include/c++/8/i686-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h

That recalls the problem on https://stackoverflow.com/a/9617178/2458991

create the right symbolic link like doing (not sure f the name `x86_64-redhat-linux`) :

```
cd /usr/include/c++/8
ln -s i686-redhat-linux x86_64-redhat-linux
```

or

```
cd /usr/include/c++/8
ln -s i686-redhat-linux/bits
```

However I hope that will not give wrong definitions with a mix 32b / 64b, do some tests after ...

Comment: For people who can't doesn't have `/usr/include/c++/8` folder , it might be `/usr/include/c++/9` on your system. You can find out the number by running `gcc -v`, look at the first number in the version line `gcc version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC) `