# qtwebengine 5.15.2 builds fails with Yocto

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, yocto, qtwebengine

I am trying to build qtwebengine 5.15.2 with Yocto for am437x-evm TI Hardware. It fails with the below error:

```
| In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/math.h:36:0,
|                  from ../../../../git/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/icu/source/i18n/csrmbcs.cpp:18:
| /usr/include/c++/7/cmath:41:10: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
|  #include <bits/c++config.h>
|           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| compilation terminated.
| [10375/15405] CC host/obj/third_party/zlib/bundled_zlib/trees.o
| [10376/15405] CXX v8_snapshot/obj/third_party/icu/bundled_icui18n/csrsbcs.o
| [10377/15405] CXX host/obj/third_party/protobuf/protoc_lib/python_generator.o
| ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I don't understand why it's trying to use the host header files while cross compiling

Anyone has any inputs on it

Comment: try adding native package of libstdc++ to depends

Answer (score 1):

As in the debug information, bitbake required c++config.h to build it and it doesn't see it.

I was able to fix it by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

If you've installed a version of gcc / g++ that doesn't ship by default (such as g++-4.8 on lucid) you'll want to match the version as well:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-multilib g++-4.8-multilib
```

[Orginal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643197/missing-include-bits-cconfig-h-when-cross-compiling-64-bit-program-on-32-bit)